# Activating conda environment in bash script that runs on startup

Tags: python, bash, conda, startup, environment

So I have a python script that generates an animation - and it requires libraries that I have in a conda environment. I need to run this script as soon as my computer turns on, so I've written a short bash script that I added to "startup applications". This bash script runs on startup, and reads like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

conda activate myenv
cd ~/scripts
python generate.py
```

When I run this in terminal myself, it's fine, but whenever I turn on the computer, the python part of the script doesn't execute, and when I check errors i find:

```
conda: command not found
```

and then i also see the python script failed to run because it's missing libraries (from the conda environment not activating)

I have tried adding lines to the bash script replacing "conda activate" with "source activate", I have tried adding `echo ". /home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc` to the bash script, replacing "conda" with `/home/barrat/anaconda3/bin/conda`, and even adding `whoami` to the bash script that runs at startup to make sure that i haven't magically become root by chance... none of this has worked. I would *really* appreciate any help. it's 3 AM and i'm a bit desperate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have solved the issue yet, but for future viewers, this worked for me:

```html
if [ -f "/path/to/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/path/to/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate myenv
fi
```

Add this instead of `conda activate myenv`.

Comment: This worked for me. Actually very hard to find this solution !

Comment: Without `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false` if you already have anaconda env initiated that starts your terminal with `(base)`

Answer (score 0):

Well as you are trying to activate an environment to start your scripts, it may also be possible for you to make a startup script itself to do the desired task by using `subprocess` module from python.

Try making a `demo.py` script like :

```
import os
import system
import subprocess
import x

subprocess.run(["command name", "value"]) #for all scripts you want to execute
```

and then you can put this python script to run at startup.
You can start quite a few amount of operations without noticable speed changes to your system and always can monitor it easily by starting the processes one after the other using `time.sleep()` in between two calls.

Comment: sorry - i think you have misuderstood. I have one script i want to run at startup - and my problem is that i can't activate the conda environment that contains the libraries that this script needs to run.

Comment: Have you tried adding conda environment and it's python to `PATH` of your operating system ? If it cannot find the installation of conda it will not be able to find anything from `python` to it's libraries.